# Inline Assembler gcc как работать со строками?

Tags: inline, gcc, ассемблер, c++, строки

Вообщем вот такая проблема. У меня есть рабочий кусок кода, написан для компилятора gcc

```
int add(int a, int b){
        int res;
        asm("movl %1, %%eax\n\
        inc %%eax\n\
        addl %2, %%eax":"=a"(res):"m"(a),"m"(b));//AT&T
      return res;
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    int a=5, b=5;
    printf("a = %d\nb = %d\n", a, b);
    int c = add(a, b);
    printf("%d + %d + 1 = %d\n", a, b, c);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Подскажите, как передать туда адрес строки и что то изменить? Пробовал через смещение `leal`, но что идет не так. Кроме рабочего куска ничего толкового не нашел, мануал не помогает.
Вики и мануал на английском не предлагать

Comment: Вы имеете в виду C++ string или сишную `char *str`?

Вообще, напишите просто код на С (или С++), что хотите получить.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){
    char str[1024];
    snprintf(str,1024,"strochka ni o chom");

    asm( "mov 2+%0,%%eax\n\t"
         "inc %%eax\n\t"
         "mov %%eax,2+%0":"=m"(str));//AT&T
    printf("%s\n",str);
    return 0;
}
```

вместо "strochka ni o chom" выводим "stsochka ni o chom". третий символ был инкрементирован по таблице ascii.